# Exporting an X11 keymap to the linux kernel

Tags: linux, layout, keyboard, x11

I was able to create a custom keymap for X11 by editing one of the useless ones in the "us" file in xkb/symbols/ and it works great once logged in. The problem is that the loadkeys/dumpkeys format is way more tedious to simply edit and dumpkeys doesn't seem to work from a Gnome Session. Is there any way to export / migrate the X11 layout to a file loadkeys can read or somehow apply it system wide so that the TTYs and login screen use my layout also?

(Ubuntu 11.04, Gnome 3)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the kernel.

Comment: I need the same thing, tryng to get customized programmers dvorak into login shell. Not sure how to convert xmodmap output into something loadkeys can read.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the easiest would be

```
setxkbmap -layout custom
dumpkeys > custom.layout
loadkeys custom.layout
```

Unfortunatelly, it is not working like this for me. I think the problem is that `dumpkeys` does not dump X11 map but underlying terminal map, but you can try if it will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `xmodmap` to edit keys. For example:
Extract existing keycodes in a file

> xmodmap -pke > ~/.xmod

Edit .xmod and then load with

> xmodmap ~/.xmod

Comment: xmodmap only works for X11 keyboard bindings. The question asks how to migrate X11 keyboard bindings for use in native Linux consoles (the ones that exist outside X), which uses a different format.